# Если бы ASP.NET Core был одно-поточен

Tags: c#, многопоточность, asp.net-core, concurrency

### Многопоточность

Согласно моему познанию `ASP.NET Core` и если сильно не углубляться в детали, то на сегодняшний день обработка HTTP-запросов на одноядерном процессоре происходит следующим образом:

1. Приложению прилетел запрос (назовем его `R1`) и его нужно обработать.
2. Из `ThreadPool` береться Поток Исполнения (`T1`) и ему передается этот запрос `R1`  для дальнейшей обработки. *Если в ThreadPool не было (случай когда это первый запрос, который обрабатывает приложение со времени запуска или все потоки заняты) свободного потока, то он создается.*
3. Обработка `R1` еще не закончилась, но приложению прилетел другой запрос (`R2`).
4. Из `ThreadPool` берётся другой поток `T2` и уже обработкой `R2`-запроса займётся `T2`.
5. Так как процессор всего один и ядро у него только одно, то на физическом уровне обработка этих двух запросов будет происходить конкурентно — процессор попеременно (каждые ~30 мл) будет выделять свое время каждому из потоков для того чтобы те имели возможность обработать свой запрос.

---

### Однопоточность

А теперь представим, что приложение `ASP.NET Core` имеет только один поток `T1`.

1. Приложению прилетел запрос `R1` и `T1` принялся к его обработке.
2. Обработка `R1` еще не закончилась, но приложению прилетает второй
   запрос `R2`.
3. И теперь потоку `T1` необходимо обработать `R2` тоже. И для этого
   организуется конкурентность, то есть, наш единственный поток
   попеременно будет переключаться с одного запроса на другой.

---

### Вопрос

**Я в начале отметил *"... и если сильно не углубляться в детали"* и возможно какие-то детали я не знаю и хотел бы узнать**. А пока, я не понимаю, разве предложенная вторая однопоточная модель не имеет место быть? Зачем нужны эти вторичные потоки, ведь процессор так и так только один? Почему он не может с одним потоком "прыгать" с запроса на запрос и попеременно обрабатывать их?

Comment: Что значит `с одним потоком "прыгать" с запроса на запрос`? Как вы это себе представляете? Вы знаете, что произойдет с потоком, если, например, набрать `Thread.Sleep(...)`?

Comment: Это просто такая архитектура реализации асинхронного исполнения. Например, в языке `Dart` нет привычных нам нитей исполнения (потоков), а есть изоляты и там действительно однопоточная схема исполнения, рекомендую к просмотру это [видео](https://youtu.be/vl_AaCgudcY).

Comment: @Bulson так это обычный цикл событий, ui поток в дотнете также работает, но там же нет конкуренции между задачами, там простое переключение во время асинхронного ожидания.

Comment: @tym32167 да, это так, но с другой стороны, нитей нет, есть только одна нитка исполнения, если надо больше, создавай изолят и обменивайся данными между ними с помощью сообщений. Зато нет проблем с гонкой и прочими прелестями  одновременного доступа к одному и тому же участку памяти, у каждого изолята своя отдельная область памяти.

Comment: @Bulson значит это не то, о чем спрашивает автор. В ui потоке в дотнетах можно также делать, создавать новые циклы сообщений поверх существующих (это называется фреймы), но так как поток один, он не будет сам по себе прыгать с одной задачи на другую, он будет это делать только когда задача закончится или когда требуется асинхронное ожидание.

Comment: @tym32167 ну, может и не то, но когда я прочитал вопрос у меня вот такой пример вспомнился, что есть языки где нет привычных нам потоков, пулов потоков, мониторов, локов и проч. Все просто и лаконично.

Comment: @tym32167, `Thread.Sleep()` блокирует текущий поток на указанное время. То есть, ты хочешь сказать, что в одно-поточном приложении у `Thread` в принципе не могло бы существовать такого метода как `Sleep()`? Или для чего приден пример этого метода?

Comment: Я хочу сказать, что если ты заблокируешь поток командой  `Thread.Sleep(...)`, или каким нибудь циклом или любой другой работой, то поток так и будет заблокированным, он не будет куда то переключаться, пока не кончится его текущая работа.

Comment: Если я правильно понял. В первом случае приложение будет прекрасно работать с обоими системами и вам не надо знать, сколько там потоков поддерживает система. Система универсальна. Во втором случае система не сможет переключиться нормально на многопоточность без доработок. Представьте, что в один прекрасный день, вы просто воткнули процессор получше.

Comment: Как мне нравится uv в этом плане. Задача делится на мелкие функции которые кладутся в кучку, а луп их по одной выполняет. Ожидание сети или диска делается простыми неблокирующими вызовами.. Только колбэк хэлл)